# Why does this regex not match in my camel route?

Tags: regex, xml, apache-camel

I want to route messages based on content, however my regex for doing so doesn't match what I throw at it. Why is that so?

I've tried some online regex test websites and on these websites, I get a full match. I've also adapted my regex to `".*\{value=1\}.*"`, which works as expected, but I think my original solution might be more robust.

This is my route:

```
<from uri="milo-client:opc.tcp://localhost:12685?allowedSecurityPolicies=None&amp;node=RAW(ns=2;s=items-machine_lfm_reset)&amp;overrideHost=true"/>
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${bodyAs(String)} regex "/\bvalue=1\b/"</simple>
        <log message="Value was 1."/>
    </when>
<choice>
```

This is the message that comes in:

```
DataValue{value=Variant{value=1}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=132061080449440000, javaDate=Thu Jun 27 11:20:44 GMT 2019}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=132061080459370000, javaDate=Thu Jun 27 11:20:45 GMT 2019}}
```

I expected this regex to match, because if I enter my message and regex on any regex testing website, I get a match, but actually I don't get a match and my when statement isn't fulfilled.

Comment: Try removing the forward slashes `"\bvalue=1\b"`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change the result

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-base/src/main/docs/simple-language.adoc) you probably should use double-backslashes as given in their example: `simple("${in.header.number} regex '\\d{4}'")`

Comment: This also doesn't change the result...

Answer (score 0):

Your input actually does not match this regex. Simple function `regex` uses `Matcher#matches()` method, which returns true only for full match.

[JDoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/1jDR)

If you have seen this regex to match in some tester website, then it is probably using `Matcher#find()`, which returns true even for partial match.

https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydc68p6r

See [Matcher#matches javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--):

> Returns:
>   true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern